# Display the last state of HTML display after clicking back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this problem let say I click an event (e.g. radio button 2) to show() div2 and hide() div1. After that I click a link to redirect to the next page.

Then I click back button (browser <-). Radio button 2 is checked, but the display is div1 instead of div2. Here is a sample source code. Could anyone help me if this can be fix.

```
<!-- test.php START -->
<div id="div_1" style="display: block;">
    <p>First Paragraph</p>
</div>
<div id="div_2" style="display: none;">
    <p>Second Paragraph</p>
</div>


<div>
    <input type="radio" id="rdo1" name="radio" checked/>First
    <input type="radio" id="rdo2" name="radio" />Second
</div>

<div>
    <a href="test1.php">Just to reload the page or go to other page</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script> 
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#rdo1").click(function () {

            $("#div_1").show();
            $("#div_2").hide();
        });

        $("#rdo2").click(function () {
            $("#div_1").hide();
            console.log('test');
            $("#div_2").show();
        });
    });
</script>
<!-- test.php END-->

<!-- test1.php START -->
 DISPLAY SOMETHING
<!-- test1.php END -->
```

Answer (score 2):

Web is **stateless** and by default the browser does not remember any settings of the previous page.. SO when you press the back button it is just like a page refresh like you opened the default page with default HTML

This is the expected and default behaviour

If you want the behavior you are expecting then you need to cache the page or store the state , either in a session or a cookie..

Answer (score 1):

You would have to save the state somehow, either server-side with ajax or form posts or via client-side with cookie or localStorage.

You can set cookies easily with the [jquery-cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) or you can use vanilla javascript to set localStorage like this quick example:

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>html5 notepad</title>
<textarea></textarea>
<script>
var n = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
n.onchange = function(){localStorage.setItem("n",n.value);}
n.value = localStorage.getItem("n");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can on DOMReady check which radio input is selected.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       var ind = $('input[name=radio]:checked').index();
       $('div[id^=div]').hide().eq(ind).show()

        $("#rdo1").click(function () {  
            $("#div_1").show();
            $("#div_2").hide();
        });

        $("#rdo2").click(function () {
            $("#div_1").hide();
            console.log('test');
            $("#div_2").show();
        });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('#rdo1').attr('checked')){
         $("#div_1").show();
         $("#div_2").hide();
}
if ($('#rdo2').attr('checked')){
         $("#div_1").hide();
         $("#div_2").show();
}

 $("#rdo1").click(function () {

    $("#div_1").show();
    $("#div_2").hide();
});

$("#rdo2").click(function () {
    $("#div_1").hide();
    console.log('test');
    $("#div_2").show();
});​
```